# Google maps api open new infowindow by clicking link inside infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow

Im trying to close old infowindow and open new infowindow (or replace content on this infowindow) but i cant get it to work. I try to Google it. 
If i now try it Google Chrome browser Developer tool's Console says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined".

```
<script>
var map;
var marker;
var markerInfoWindow;

function intMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(60.3000216, 24.944929),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // Create a new marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ draggable: true, icon: 'images/new_marker.png' });
    var markerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
        marker.setMap(map);

        var contentString = "<a href='#' onclick='openNew();'>Click here to open new infowindow!</a>";
        var markerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });            
        markerInfoWindow.open(map, marker);
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            markerInfoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
}         
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", intMap);

    function openNew() {
        markerInfoWindow.close();
        var contentString = "Open this infowind when clicked link";
        var markerInfoWindowNew = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });  
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got problem with scope of variable `markerInfoWindow` - in your code you create new local which hides external one

```
var map;
var marker;
var markerInfoWindow;

function intMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(60.3000216, 24.944929),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // Create a new marker
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        draggable: true,
        icon: 'images/new_marker.png'
    });
    markerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
        marker.setMap(map);

        var contentString = "<a href='#' onclick='openNew();'>Click here to open new infowindow!</a>";
        markerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });
        markerInfoWindow.open(map, marker);
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            markerInfoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", intMap);

function openNew() {
    markerInfoWindow.close();
    var contentString = "Open this infowind when clicked link";
    markerInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    markerInfoWindow.open(map, marker);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now i can close that 'markerInfoWindow' but it's not open new 'markerInfoWindowNew' infowindow.

Comment: @user2885442 checkout updated code. 1) you forgot to open info window: ```markerInfoWindow.open(map, marker);``` ; 2) again, ```map``` was shadowed inside ```intMap```. Hence, external ```map``` instance was always ```null```